# How to make table inline with the p tag

Tags: html, css

I am stuck at one place where I need to make a table inline with the `p tag` but I am not able to do so. I want to do minimalist change in my HTML Style. Below is what I have tried

```
<p>ABCD</p>
<table style = display: inline;>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>State&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Capital&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Zip&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>New Yrk&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Alba ny&nbsp;</td>
         <td>13210&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/h5bbs0oy/

Comment: You cannot have spaces and no quotes.

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h5bbs0oy/1/

Comment: @Michelangelo Agreed. I just pointed out OPs mistakes.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping a beginner. Appreciate it!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok, cool. Sometimes it's hard to flag a question, because it is not a duplicate of something but it's so common that it pollutes the forum. Maybe there should be something like: question can be closed and give a reference to documentation.

Comment: @Michelangelo That's why we built the epic fail documentation. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar LoL. Maybe an idea that new comers < 50 rep. are forced looking up the documentation first and if they can't find an answer then they are allowed to post a question.

Comment: @Michelangelo Good idea, we can propose. See, one thing is, I am experienced in HTML, CSS, not in Android. Can't help cross experts. Obviously, the other experts have huge rep. Can do based on their current tags, but still that won't be perfect.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok, cool! Yes, that is a problem. Although experienced SO users should know that a lot can found by digging the forum. You are on the team of SO devs?

Comment: @Michelangelo Na, but well, I have a great hold on SO stuff.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You cannot have spaces inside the attributes, if you aren't enclosing them inside quotes.
2. You need to make the `<p>` inline as well.

**Solution**

```
<p style="display: inline;">ABCD</p>
<table style="display: inline;">
```

**Snippet**

```html
<p style="display: inline;">ABCD</p>
<table style="display: inline;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>State&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Capital&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Zip&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New Yrk&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Alba ny&nbsp;</td>
      <td>13210&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. :)

Comment: @Unbreakable Why did you change the accepted answer?

Comment: I did not realize. I am sorry.

Comment: @Unbreakable No worries. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at making both the paragraph and table inline, then have the ***display: inline*** on both the tags.

```
<p style="display: inline">ABCD</p>
<table style="display: inline">...
```

Comment: turned out we answered it at the same time :)

Comment: You didn't see how to format the answer, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. `:D`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Making both display:inline works, but  it will good if you   only make `p tag` float:left . No need to add display:inline on any of one, Also adding display:inline, you will not be able to add top and bottom padding or margin.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make table inline using inline CSS Method, just follow this method:

```html
<table style="display: inline">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>State&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Capital&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Zip&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New Yrk&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Alba ny&nbsp;</td>
      <td>13210&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The quotes in inline css was missing